# C++ matrix multiplication - recover 3D coords from depth image

Tags: c++, matrix, 3d, coordinates

I have following problem:

I have a set of depth-images of the same object from different directions and I have data for camera calibration. Now I want to transform those pixel coordinates with the given depth value into world points, so I can use those points as a mesh.

I know that to get a point *Pw* in the real world from pixel coordinates *Px* following equation holds:

*Pw* = *K* * [*R*  *t*] * *Px*

while the intrinsic matrix *K* = [f 0 pp; 0 f pp; 0 0 1 ] with *f* being the focal length and *pp* the principle point and the extrinsic matrix consisting of the 3x3 rotation matrix R* and the 3x1 translation matrix *t*.

My questions are now the following:
How do I multiply the matrices, in which order? I know that matrices have to be multiplied from right to left, meaning first *extrinsic* = [*R* * *t*] and then the *K* * *extrinsic*. Or multiply first the 2D coordinate (incl. depth as Z) with *extrinsic*-matrix and then multiply K with the result?

Also, is there some std function that does matrix*matrix matrix*vector multiplication or do I have to implement it with std::vector/array?

Answer (score 0):

They are plenty of libs to handle matrix computation, you can use boost http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix.htm.

Answer (score 0):

The projection from world (`Pw`) to image / pixel (`Px`) coordinates can be written as:

```
Px ~= z Px = K (R Pw + t)
```

where `~=` is "proportional to" (after the perspective division), also note that `K` preserves the `z` coordinate.

This equation can be inverted as:

```
Pw = R* (K^-1 z Px - t)
```

where `R*` is the transpose (and inverse) of `R`.

So if the image / pixel coordinates of the point and its depth (from the range image) are known, then its world coordinates can be recovered using the last equation.

To answer the 2nd question: there are currently no functionality to do matrix computations in the STL. The [Eigen library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) is a possible candidate often used for computer vision / graphics applications.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Could you tell me the dimensionalities of your inverted equation?
I guess R* and K^-1 are (3x3) matrices and t is (3x1). Is z just a vector with (0, 0, z) or is it just the value z itself?
Also in which order do I solve this equation?  First the term in the brackets minus t ..? Im sorry, Im kinda a slow thinker

Comment: Yes, `R*` and `K^-1` are 3 x 3 matrices, and `t` is a vector (so 3 x 1). `z` is a scalar, so the z / depth value itself. To apply the second equation, evaluate the term in parentheses and then multiply the result by `R*`.